# Streamlining logging inside of a URL health-checking PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Trying to streamline logging inside of a URL health-checking PowerShell script.  It works the way I want except `Start-Transcript` gives output which is too verbose and repeating itself.    Based on this [article](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3567), the default Debug/Verbose Preferences are set to SilentlyContinue at initialSessionState which prevents the output to the host.  But it's showing as the script output  which is behavior I'm trying to eliminate.

**The Script:**

```
#Place URL list file in the below path
$URLListFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL Check\URL_Check.txt"
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#For every URL in the list
Foreach($Uri in $URLList) {
    try{
        #For proxy systems
        [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
        [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

        #Web request
        $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
        $res = $req.GetResponse()
    }catch {
        #Err handling
        $res = $_.Exception.Response
    }
    $req = $null

    #Getting HTTP status code
    $int = [int]$res.StatusCode

    #Writing to Log file
    Start-Transcript -append -path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\z_Logs\URL Check\URL_Check_log.txt"
    #Writing on the screen
    Write-Host "$int - $uri"
    #Stopping logging
    Stop-Transcript
    
    #Disposing response if available
    if($res){
        $res.Dispose()
    }
}
```

**Current output:**

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20201229205017
Username: ALPHA\Admin
RunAs User: ALPHA\Admin
Configuration Name: 
Machine: OPTIPLEX (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Host Application: powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL_Check\URL_Check.ps1
Process ID: 520
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1171
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\z_Logs\URL_Check\URL_Check_log.txt
200 - https://ems.alpha.local:1443/
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20201229205017
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20201229205017
Username: ALPHA\Admin
RunAs User: ALPHA\Admin
Configuration Name: 
Machine: OPTIPLEX (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Host Application: powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL_Check\URL_Check.ps1
Process ID: 520
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1171
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\z_Logs\URL_Check\URL_Check_log.txt
200 - https://hpna.alpha.local:4443/
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20201229205017
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20201229205018
Username: ALPHA\Admin
RunAs User: ALPHA\Admin
Configuration Name: 
Machine: OPTIPLEX (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Host Application: powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL_Check\URL_Check.ps1
Process ID: 520
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1171
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\z_Logs\URL_Check\URL_Check_log.txt
200 - http://login.microsoftonline.com/
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20201229205018
**********************
```

**The simplified output I'm looking for:**

```
200 - https://ems.alpha.local:1443/
200 - https://hpna.alpha.local:4443/ 
200 - http://login.microsoftonline.com/
```

Not sure that it matters but I'm calling this script from a one-line command file like this (which I'm not trying to change):

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL_Check\URL_Check.ps1"
```

Comment: I don't think this is caused by the verbose or debug preferences. It looks like standard transcript data.  At version 5 transcripts started including these wordy headers etc...  Why not switch to simply writing the output to the log with Out-File and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply remove the `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` calls and capture an array of formatted strings from the foreach loop.

Then display that on screen and write to file:

```
#Place URL list file in the below path
$URLListFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\URL Check\URL_Check.txt"
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#For every URL in the list
$result = foreach($Uri in $URLList) {
    try{
        #For proxy systems
        [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
        [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

        #Web request
        $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
        $res = $req.GetResponse()
    }
    catch {
        #Err handling
        $res = $_.Exception.Response
    }
    $req = $null

    #Getting HTTP status code
    $int = [int]$res.StatusCode

    # output a formatted string to capture in variable $result
    "$int - $uri"

    #Disposing response if available
    if($res){
        $res.Dispose()
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

#output to log file
$result | Set-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\z_Logs\URL Check\URL_Check_log.txt" -Force
```

Comment: Perfect, that was the issue.